# HtmlAgilityPack returning random characters

Tags: httpwebrequest, html-agility-pack, streamreader

I have the following code that is using HtmlAgilityPack to pull back html code for a number of websites. All seems to be working well, apart from asos.com. When running a url through, it returns random characters (‹\b\0\0\0\0\0\0UÍÂ „ï&¾CãÁ¢ø›\bãhìÁ3-«`Zi`ý}z‘š/»ómf³Ü`]In@iÉÑbr[œ¡Ä¬v7Ðœ¶7N[GáôSv;Ü°?[†.ã*3Ž¢G×ù6OƒäwPŒõH\rÙ¸\vzìmèÎ;M›4q_K¨Ð)

```
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.OptionReadEncoding = false;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.asos.com/ASOS/ASOS-Sweatshirt-With-Contrast-Ribs/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2765751&cid=14368&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Red");
    request.Timeout = 10000;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 32000;
    request.UserAgent = "TEST";
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Accept = "text/html";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default); //put your encoding            
    doc.Load(reader);

    string html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

I have ran the url through Fiddler, however cant seem to see anything to suggest there should be a problem. Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

See header image from fiddler here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LRFY.png

Comment: What's the url you're downloading from exactly?

Comment: http://www.asos.com/ASOS/ASOS-Sweatshirt-With-Contrast-Ribs/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2765751&cid=14368&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Red

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Html Agility Pack, it's because you have set `AllowAutoRedirect` to false. Remove it and it will work. The site apparently does a redirect, you need to follow it if you want the final HTML text.

Note the Html Agility Pack has a utility `HtmlWeb` class that can download file directly as an `HmlDocument`:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(@"http://www.asos.com/ASOS/ASOS-Sweatshirt-With-Contrast-Ribs/Prod/pgeproduct.aspx?iid=2765751&cid=14368&sh=0&pge=0&pgesize=20&sort=-1&clr=Red");
```